# receiving memory warning issue in iphone when taking picture from iphone camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

i have a problem while i am taking snap from iphone camera then i receive this error on device console "Received memory warning". while i am pick snap from iphone photo libarary then i dont get any memory warning issue. this is the code below

```
    -(IBAction)uploadImageBtn:(id)sender
    {

        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
        @try
        {
            UIImagePickerController *pickImage = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
            pickImage.delegate = (id)self;

            if (btn.tag == 2)
            {
                if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary ])
                {
                    pickImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                    [self presentViewController:pickImage animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
                else
                {
                    UIAlertView *alertVw = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Photo library not exist" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alertVw show];
                }
            }

            else if (btn.tag == 3)
            {
                if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera ])
                {
                    pickImage.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                    [self presentViewController:pickImage animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
                else
                {
                    UIAlertView *alertVw = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Camera not working " delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alertVw show];
                }
            }

        }

        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            NSLog(@"exception %@",exception);
        }


       }


// uiimage picker view controller delegate method 

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    @try {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        // Edited image works great (if you allowed editing)
        myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

        // AND the original image works great
        myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        myImage =  [myImage fixOrientation];

        // AND do whatever you want with it, (NSDictionary *)info is fine now
        //  fixOrObj = [[fixorientation alloc]init];
        //  myImage = [fixOrObj  fixOrientation];

        dataObj = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0);



        HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];


        HUD.delegate = (id)self;
        HUD.labelText = @"Uploading image";
        [self performSelector:@selector(uploadimages) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"exception %@",exception);
    }
}
```

kinsly solve this issue i trying it for two days but cant succeeded

Comment: Memory warning is normal while presenting UIImagePickerController.

Comment: You should be only concern if this memory warning crashes your application. Opening camera using UIImagePickerController is memory extensive operation.

Comment: then what is the solution to solve it.

Comment: i don't understand  your this term Opening camera using UIImagePickerController is memory extensive operation

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can decrease the size of the photo.Because the photo you are taking has high resolution and big in size so first you scale down the size like below.

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   CGSize sizeCropped = CGSizeMake(602, 450);//you can give any size
  UIImage *theimage = nil;
theimage = [yourclassname imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:sizeCropped];

  //you can do here whatever you want with theImage
      [imgPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 }

+ (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
          scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!!